# Is there a possible way to run two parameterized testng.xml files?

Tags: selenium, gradle, testng, build.gradle, testng.xml

Is there any way to run these two xml files parallel?

test1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UFT-8">
<suite name="Runner">
<listeners>
<listener class-name = "package1.Tester"/>
</listener>
<parameter name = "Excel name" value = "Excel1"/>
<test name = "Excel" parallel = "tests" thread-count="1" verbose = "2">
<classes>
<class name = "package2.Run"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

test2.xml
same as test1.xml only the parameter value differs from Excel1 to Excel2

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31851469/5226491.

Comment: Above one doesnot work for me It throws an error saying Unable to parse file path(test,xml) specified

Answer (score 0):

1 You have an issue in testNG XML:

Instead of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UFT-8">` (note UFT is typo, also `?` missed) should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

2 Once you fix this, just create 2 files `test1.xml`, `test2.xml` as you want and create a new `runSuites.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Run-all-testNG-files">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="test1.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="test2.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```